# Workout meaning in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

What meaning of workout in this sentence:

> I wear jeans with commitment and obsession. I really give them a workout.

Answer (score 0):

A "workout" is, for a person, a session of intense physical activity, usually to increase physical fitness. "I did a 30-minute workout on the treadmill." "I didn't realize shelving books all day would be such a workout." Usages like your example extends the meaning to inanimate objects (a bit of [personification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personification)).